# Outlook 2010 add in in C#

Tags: outlook

I want to optimize Outlook 2010 add in in C#, I use Outlook 2010 add in available in C#. But I don't seem to be able to figure out the solutions.
My problems is outlook just allow add new tab and can not add textbox like below image. Attempts to find some solutions but i still not find out. Can I add a button and a textbox like below link image. 
Thanks in advance!
http://www.mediafire.com/download/o54low704w5kfva/detail.png

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add to or remove controls from built-in groups in the Ribbon. You can rebuild the whole ribbon from scratch specifying built-in controls with idMso values, only in that case you will be able to add custom controls to built-in groups in the Ribbon.

Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

> My problems is outlook just allow add new tab and can not add textbox like below image.

You may consider developing a form region where can use any Windows Forms controls for displaying attached files.

Also you may consider attaching files to the Outlook item and displaying them in the natural way. But in the `ItemSend` event of the Application class or the `Send` event you may remove such attachments and upload them wherever you need. You may add a user property for differentiating them from regular attachments.